# FirebaseAuth requests blocked by cors policy in js app

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, cors, firebase-hosting

I know that similar questions exist, but I didn't find a solution for me.
I have a built-in Flutter web app that is compiled into javascript. I had it hosted on Firebase Hosting. The in-app first screen is the login page which uses FirebaseAuth for logging. Whenever the first time website is open - all internal library requests have status failed. When after that I press CTRL+F5 everything works smoothly.
Here is a comparison of the same first internal request. On left is successful one, on right one which fails due to "** has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'."
[image: left is a successful one, on right one which fails]

I found out about the configuration of headers for Firebase Hosting, so I did it:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {

    "source": "**",
    "headers": [ 
    {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value": "*"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "value": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    },
    {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "value": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
      } 
    ]
  }]
  }
}
```

In app there is a simple initialization of a firebase in didChangeDependencies with required data. Then FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...) On index.html section about firebase:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

I have tested it in Chrome many times and always failed. Only on localhost runs smoothly

More info:
requests on "normal" (without clearing cache) return to page:
[image] 
requests after CTRL+F5 on the same site:
[image]
Those blurred on red are the URL of my app

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache..? You said on cntrl+F5 its working. So some times clearing cache helps..

Comment: But when and how clearing cache? In code? Currently always after opening site always CTRL+F5 is required. But I'm looking for reason - what exactly changes after clearing cache that CORS to Google API suddenly works and how can I achieve that by code - maybe some token is refreshing (which one and how to force refresh of it)

Comment: I'm asking to clear the cache in browser. I'm also just wondering how cors request is passing when you press cntl+f5, so I am just guessing, is it something related to browsers cache..

Comment: @aravind your idea sadly is exactly the same as CTRL+F5. It works only one-time

Comment: I updated question with list of all network requests

Comment: Does the site load normally from then on after you've ctrl+F5ed once or do you need to ctrl+F5 every other time to get it to behave normally?

Comment: @JLowther every time I open.it again after sucessful login it requires ctrl+f5. Only when tab isn't closed than back and forward site navigation doesn't broke logging. But typical refresh brokes it again nad clearing cookies by ctrl+f5 is required

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue was from the service worker blocking Firebase Auth calls on web. This has been fixed as mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49716). Updating to the latest version of `firebase_auth plugin` should fix the issue.